# Access variable from a different class in a different package?

Tags: java, netbeans, game-physics

I want to set it so igAS for each igCharacter will be limited by a variable in igMech.
Here is what I have
first :

```
    package igCharacters;
    import igMech.*;
    protected class igBrand {
            public double igAS = .77;
    }
```

second:

```
    package igMech;
    class igLimits {
            double aSLimit = 2.5
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you explain it better?

Comment: So, we must guess what's `igAs` & `igCharacter` ..... emm tricky question I like it.

Comment: okay. I want to have igAS from igBrand class to compare with the aSLimit in igLimits class. does that help?

Comment: igAttackSpeed - in game

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* you might want to use the `public` modifier (although it's quite hard to tell what you mean from your question). You are using default, which is package-private (i.e. not accessible from any class outside the package `igMech`). Using `public` means a class is visible from any package.

```
package igCharacters;
import igMech.*;
protected class igBrand {
  public double igAS = .77;
}

package igMech;
public class igLimits { // now visible from the igCharacters package
  public double aSLimit = 2.5
}
```