# How to access a public variable from a class that is NOT in a package from a class that IS in a package

Tags: java, package

It is possible to get a public variable (let's call this "var") from class A in package Aa from class B in package Bb by doing

`package Bb;`

`import Aa.A;
public class B {
    int neededVar = A.var
}`

but how do I access "var" if A is not inside any package?

Edit: This question is different from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16594052/access-variable-from-a-different-class-in-a-different-package). That question is asking how to access a variable that is in a class that is **ALSO** in a package from a class that is in a different package.

Comment: If there is no specified package for a class it's placed in `default package` and you can't import classes from `default package`.

Comment: @mjsoft It's not a duplicate. If you read the link, the asker was asking how to access a variable in a package from a package. Hence why I bolded NOT in my question title.

Comment: One of these ought to be a duplicate then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193226/how-to-import-a-class-from-default-package , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030148/whats-the-syntax-to-import-a-class-in-a-default-package-in-java :D

Comment: @user2864740 Ah I see. I didn't know of the term "default package" as to why it did not show up when I searched for it.

Comment: Is `var` a field of an *instance* of `A`, or is it a (`static`) field of the *class* `A`?

Comment: @Bohemian static

Comment: @Illiyan then what's the problem here? If you have `public static int var = 42;` then your code should work. Are you getting a compile error? If so, what is it?

Comment: @Bohemian It not so much a compile error? Initially, I thought it would be similar to accessing a variable from another package so I tried A.var (this is inside of class B) but A is an "unrecognized symbol" according to the ide.

Comment: Does the line `import Aa.A;` compile OK? If so, I don't know what the problem could be.

Comment: Sorry, it may have been confusing when I asked the question. Class A is NOT in package Aa - Class A is not in any package (except the default package which I now know of). I was trying to clarify that my question was not the same as the top google search result.

Comment: Class A (if is not in a package) will most definitely be in the <default package>. But you cannot import classes from the default package and in general this package should be avoided. Paragraph 7.5 : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se6/html/packages.html

Comment: Why not move your class to its own package?

Answer (score 1):

*It is possible to get a public variable (let's call this "var") from class A ***in package*** Aa from class B ***in package*** Bb* - this means that both classes ARE in the packages. So to access to `var` you need an instance of class `A` and to get `var` contained in this instance. So you could do something like this in class `B`:

```
A objA = new A();
int neededVar = objA.var;
```

But if the class you need to use in package `Bb` isn't contained in any package specified by you with the words `package`... in the very beginning (not counting comments) of Java file containing it , it is put into `default` package. You cannot use classes contained in `default` package in any other classes than contained in `default` package too.

Comment: @user2864740 You are right, I edited my answer and hope it clarifies the problem now. Thank you for pointing it out.